# Dealing with errors in promises that are unanticipated and thus don't trigger reject()

Tags: javascript, error-handling, promise, es6-promise, catch-block

In the following javascript code, why does the error (generated by the assignment to an non-existing object property inside the promise) not get caught by the .catch() on the promise, but does get caught by the window.onunhandledrejection function? I would like to be able to catch errors in my promises using .catch() even if they are not errors I have thought of in advance and thus haven't thought to write code to explicitly call reject().

```
window.onunhandledrejection = function( error ) {
    console.log(error.reason);
};

function test() {
    return new Promise( async function( resolve, reject ) {
        objectThatDoesntExist.property = 1;
    } );
}

test().catch( (error) => { console.log("Caught " + error) } );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `async` from the `new Promise( async function( ...))` and it works as expected.  That `async` is catching the exception and turning it into a rejected promise which the promise is not expecting.  It is not part of the contract with the `new Promise()` constructor that you pass it a function that returns a promise that it should pay attention to.

Instead, the Promise constructor catches synchronous exceptions in the executor function or waits for you to call the `resolve()` or `reject()` callbacks and pays zero attention to whatever is returned from the executor callback function.

You can see here that if you remove the `async` keyword, then it works as expected and the exception is caught in the `.catch()`.

```js
function test() {
    return new Promise(function( resolve, reject ) {
        objectThatDoesntExist.property = 1;
    } );
}

test().catch( (error) => { console.log("Caught " + error) } );
```

Note: One might ask "why" the Promise constructor doesn't support the case when it's made `async`.  It seems like a promise-friendly thing to do.  I don't know the actual logic that went into the decision not to support that, but I do know that whenever you're using `async` inside a `new Promise()` executor function, that's typically a sign that you don't need the `new Promise()` wrapper at all.  If you're using `async` for a reason, then you already have promises.  If you already have promises, then you typically don't need to wrap it in `new Promise()` as you can use/return the promises you already have.

Comment: … or alternatively just omit the `new Promise` stuff and write simply `async function test() {  objectThatDoesntExist.property = 1; }`

Comment: @Bergi - Except I think the whole point of the question is why the promise constructor wasn't giving the desired outcome in this case.

Comment: All of this information was useful to me (as someone relatively new to js) so thank you.